# Collision detection: CSS only changes when *first* div hits footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision-detection, collision

I'm still having trouble getting my collision detection setup to work correctly. Currently, whenever the divs fall onto the footer, only when the first div actually hits the footer do the other divs change color/CSS. Here's a gif of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaaRj.gif

What I WANT is to have each individual div change color when it hits the footer class. I think only the JS is the necessary info in this case, but let me know if the HTML/CSS is needed too.

**JS:**

```
var links = ["#portfolio", "#hamumu", "#beep", "#jk"];

$(document).ready(function() {

    //if on home page
    if ($("body#home").length > 0) {

        homePage();

    //else if on portfolio page
    } else if ($("body#portfolio").length > 0) {

          //run portfolio function
          portfolioPage();
    }
});

//home page function
function homePage() {

    //initial animations(Math.random()*(2)+1)
    for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {

        //animate links
        $(links[i]).animate({
            //have each image fall
            top: '0'
            //put in a slightly random time
        }, 2000*(Math.random()*(3)+1), 'easeOutBounce');
    }    
}

window.setInterval(function() {

    for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {

        var link = $(links[i]);
        var footer = $(".footer");

        var x1 = link.offset().left;
        var y1 = link.offset().top;
        var h1 = link.outerHeight(true);
        var w1 = link.outerWidth(true);
        var b1 = y1 + h1;
        var r1 = x1 + w1;

        var x2 = footer.offset().left;
        var y2 = footer.offset().top;
        var h2 = footer.outerHeight(true);
        var w2 = footer.outerWidth(true);
        var b2 = y2 + h2;
        var r2 = x2 + w2;

        if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) {
            return false;
        }

        changeColors(link);
    }

}, 20);

function changeColors(link) {

        link.css("background-color", "red");
}
```

Comment: Can you set up a http://jsfiddle.net of the issue? Seeing it directly is 1,000,000x better than a GIF

Comment: Jose may have answered my question below, but I will definitely try to make a habit of this in the future. My problem is I'm unsure how to "add in" external plugins, like "jquery.easing.1.3.js". (I make use of this: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **not** be using `setInterval` to periodically check if the elements have reached the footer. jQuery's `animate` has [several callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) that you can define to get information about the progress of the animation.

For instance, there's the `step` callback that is called once for each animated property of each animated element. That's where you should place your *collision detection* code.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcrmq8dj/) I've just created.

Comment: Great info, thanks. However, I don't understand what (n, t) do here. http://api.jquery.com/animate/ mentions "Function( Number now, Tween tween)" but what does that mean in simple terms?

Comment: I should have used more descriptive names, but essentially the first argument is the position of the element at that moment, and the second argument is an object, that you can ignore, with more information about the animation.

Comment: Okay, so in this case "n" is essentially the same as "$(links[i])"?

Comment: Nope, `n` would be the same as `$(links[i]).css('top')`

Comment: Hmmm, okay. I guess that makes sense.